# How to fix lag occurring while transitioning images?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I implemented a simple view with 4 images. These images are exchanged when the let selected is changed. That works really good. The problem is that there is a significant lag/freeze and CPU usage of the simulator is 100% for a few seconds while the images transition. All images are local and compressed to about 0.5-1.5Megabyte.

```
//Same Extension
struct ContentView:View {
    let set1 = ["pic1", "pic2", "pic3","pic4"]
    let set2 = ["pic5", "pic6", "pic7","pic8"]
    @State private var useSet1 = true
    @State private var position: Int?

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 380,height: 440)
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
                LazyVStack(spacing:0){
                    Text("Text Here for pic Set 1")
                    .padding(.top,10)
                    .padding(.leading,15)
                    .padding(.trailing,20)
                    .frame(width: 380,height: 440, alignment: .topLeading)
                    .id(1)
                    Text("Text Here for pic Set 2")
                    .padding(.top,10)
                    .padding(.leading,15)
                    .padding(.trailing,20)
                    .frame(width: 380,height: 440, alignment: .topLeading)
                    .id(2)
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .scrollPosition(id: $position)
            .onChange(of: position) {
                withAnimation{
                    useSet1.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 380,height: 440)
        
        HStack{
            VStack{
                Image(useSet1 ? set1[0] : set2[0])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                Image(useSet1 ? set1[1] : set2[1])   
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .clipped()
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.top,10)

            }
            .padding(.trailing,5)
            VStack{
                Image(useSet1 ? set1[2] : set2[2])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .clipped()
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.bottom,5)
                Image(useSet1 ? set1[3] : set2[3])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.top,5)
            }
            .padding(.leading,5)
        }
        .padding(15)
        .frame(width: 450, height: 440)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18, style: .continuous))
    }
}
```

I̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶i̶m̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶i̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶w̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶i̶m̶a̶g̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶s̶.̶ ̶I̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶u̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶a̶g̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶c̶a̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶i̶m̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶d̶e̶l̶e̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶.̶.̶.̶ ̶B̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶a̶g̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶t̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶.̶ I think it is pretty cpu intensive to render 4 images at a time but I found no easy solution to fix this problem. What I think could work is to preload the images when the view is created but I have now idea how to do that with a local SwiftData db.

**Edit:**
Here is the new code with 3 image sets:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let set1 = ["pic1", "pic2", "pic3", "pic4"]
    let set2 = ["pic6", "pic5", "pic7", "pic8"]
    let set3 = ["pic1", "pic2", "pic3", "pic4"]
    @State private var useSet = 1 
    @State private var position: Int?
    @State private var isAnimating = false
    @State private var oldPosition: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 380, height: 440)
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) { setId in
                        Text("Text Here for pic Set \(setId)")
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                            .padding(.leading, 15)
                            .padding(.trailing, 20)
                            .frame(width: 380, height: 440, alignment: .topLeading)
                            .id(setId)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .scrollPosition(id: $position)
            .customOnChange(value: position) { newValue, oldValue in
                guard let oldPosition else {
                    self.oldPosition = newValue
                    return
                }
                if let oldValue = oldValue {
                    print("iOS 17+")
                    if isAnimating {
                        self.position = oldValue ?? 0
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    print("iOS 16")
                    if isAnimating {
                        self.position = oldPosition
                        return
                    }
                }
                guard !isAnimating else { return }
                isAnimating = true
                self.oldPosition = newValue ?? 0
                let duration: Double = 0.3
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: duration)) {
                    useSet = newValue ?? 1
                }
                let delay: Double = duration + 0.05
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                    isAnimating = false
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 380, height: 440)
        .padding(.top, 100)
        
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Image(currentSet()[0])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                Image(currentSet()[1])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .clipped()
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.top, 10)
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 5)
            VStack {
                Image(currentSet()[2])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .clipped()
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.bottom, 5)
                Image(currentSet()[3])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.top, 5)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 5)
        }
        .padding(15)
        .frame(width: 450, height: 440)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18, style: .continuous))
    }
    func currentSet() -> [String] {
            switch useSet {
            case 1:
                return set1
            case 2:
                return set2
            case 3:
                return set3
            default:
                return set1
            }
        }
}
```

**Current status of investigation**
This fixes the lag between image sets
`withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.1).delay(0)) {`

There is a special lag when you swipe the first time.
This can be fixed by using a higher delay. But it is so high that it looks bad.

`withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.1).delay(1)) {`

Comment: What is SelectedPoint? I can' reproduce any lag. Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code so it is easy to reproduce. You need 8 images with name pic1 to pic8 and than you can test it yourself. To replicate the problem use images with different aspect ratios and click the switch button.

I discovered 2 new things.
1. It has nothing todo with SwiftData because the same problem is in my demo code
2. It **is** a problem with the animation. I think it is because it has to animate between the different aspect ratios of the images. But my app needs the slightly different aspect ratios of the pictures...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with a bit of a workaround. To fix the lag while scrolling though the scrollview I shortened the animation:
`withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1)) {`

The lag caused by the first swiping was apparently some error in one of my pictures. I just changed the order in the scrollview and the lag actually disappeared completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to too many animations/updates being fired at a time. I can only think of that at least. So, I thought limiting the times the animation can be triggered could be a way to go. I added a new `@State` boolean property which will tell us if the animation is ongoing and block the action if that property is true:

```
struct ContentView:View {
let set1 = ["Pic 1", "Pic 2", "Pic 4","Pic 5"]
let set2 = ["Pic 6", "Pic 7", "Pic 8","Pic 9"]
@State private var useSet1 = true
@State private var isAnimating = false

var body: some View {
    Button("switch") {
        guard !isAnimating else { return }
        isAnimating = true
        let duration: Double = 0.4
        withAnimation(.spring(duration: duration)) {
            useSet1.toggle()
        }
        let delay: Double = duration + 0.05
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
            isAnimating = false
        }
    }
    /// The rest is the same
}
```

As you can see I used a delay to reset the `isAnimating` property to false and allow the animation to be fired again. Also, the animaition need to have a set duration for this to work properly.
**Note:** This won't be 100% smooth but, It will reduce the lagginess by a lot.

**Edit:** Since the approach of above is not enough and you told me you are using a paginated scroll view, an idea popped to my mind, that you may not be using a **Lazy** kind of stack to display those images. Say you have 100 of those items each one of them showing four images you are going to run out of memory pretty soon!
So I've created a small example with what I had using `LazyHStack` to show you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var useSet1 = true
    @State private var isAnimating = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("switch") {
                guard !isAnimating else { return }
                isAnimating = true
                let duration: Double = 0.3
                withAnimation(.spring(duration: duration)) {
                    useSet1.toggle()
                }
                let delay: Double = duration + 0.05
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                    isAnimating = false
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                /// USE LazyHStack HERE!!!
                LazyHStack {
                    ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { _ in
                        ImagesView(useSet1: $useSet1)
                            .safeAreaPadding(.horizontal, 30)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct ImagesView: View {
    private let set1 = ["Pic 1", "Pic 2", "Pic 3","Pic 4"]
    private let set2 = ["Pic 5", "Pic 6", "Pic 7","Pic 8"]
    @Binding var useSet1: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack{
                Image(useSet1 ? set1[0] : set2[0])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                Image(useSet1 ? set1[1] : set2[1])             .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .clipped()
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.top,10)
            }
            .padding(.trailing,5)
            VStack{
                Image(useSet1 ? set1[2] : set2[2])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .clipped()
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.bottom,5)
                
                Image(useSet1 ? set1[3] : set2[3])
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                    .padding(.top,5)
            }
            .padding(.leading,5)
        }
        .padding(15)
        .frame(width: 450, height: 440)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18, style: .continuous))
    }
}
```

Here's the difference between using `LazyHStack` and not using it:

[image: Using LazyHStack]

Using the simple `HStack` and pressing the button 3-4 times this is what happen:

[image: Using HStack]

This is crazy!

So, according to me, this is what is happening to you, otherwise, without more code I really would not know.

**Edit 2:** After seeing your code and trying it out myself I've found the **delay** was the solution, although with slightly more refined approach. I've written a custom `onChange` modifier to support both iOS 16 and 17:

```
extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func customOnChange<Value: Equatable>(value: Value, initial: Bool = false, completion: @escaping (Value, Value?) -> Void) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 17, *) {
            self
                .onChange(of: value, initial: initial) { oldValue, newValue in
                    completion(newValue, oldValue)
                }
        } else {
            self
                .onChange(of: value) { newValue in
                    completion(newValue, nil)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    if initial {
                        completion(value, nil)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And then edited your code like so:

```
struct ContentView:View {
private let set1 = ["Pic 1", "Pic 2", "Pic 3","Pic 4"]
private let set2 = ["Pic 5", "Pic 6", "Pic 7","Pic 8"]
@State private var useSet1 = true
@State private var position: Int?
@State private var isAnimating = false
@State private var oldPosition: Int?


var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
            .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
            .frame(width: 380,height: 440)
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
            LazyVStack(spacing:0){
                Text("Text Here for pic Set 1")
                .padding(.top,10)
                .padding(.leading,15)
                .padding(.trailing,20)
                .frame(width: 380,height: 440, alignment: .topLeading)
                .id(1)
                Text("Text Here for pic Set 2")
                .padding(.top,10)
                .padding(.leading,15)
                .padding(.trailing,20)
                .frame(width: 380,height: 440, alignment: .topLeading)
                .id(2)
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .scrollPosition(id: $position)
        .customOnChange(value: position) { newValue, oldValue in
            guard let oldPosition else {
                self.oldPosition = newValue
                return
            }
            if let oldValue = oldValue {
                print("iOS 17+")
                if isAnimating {
                    self.position = oldValue ?? 0
                    return
                }
            } else {
                print("iOS 16")
                if isAnimating {
                    self.position = oldPosition
                    return
                }
            }
            guard !isAnimating else { return }
            isAnimating = true
            self.oldPosition = newValue ?? 0
            let duration: Double = 0.3
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: duration)) {
                useSet1.toggle()
            }
            let delay: Double = duration + 0.05
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                isAnimating = false
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 380,height: 440)
    .padding(.top, 100)
    
     /// The rest is the same
}
```

Let me know your thoughts on this approach!

Comment: I tried something like that but the problem is that my usecase doesn't really allow it. In my real application the main feature of the app is a scrollview with
.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging) and by swiping through the scrollview the 4 pictures  get changed. So it would be not possible to implement some sort of block period. What could work is a that not all 4 images are are animated at the same time and instead there is a small delay between each image. Do you think something like that could work and improve the situation?

Comment: Yes, animations support delays too: .spring.delay(duration). Something like this. Let me know.

Comment: I implemented that every image has a different delay but the cpu usage is still 100% if I swipe up and down.

.animation(.spring().delay(0.6), value: selected.viewedItem.picture2)
Do you have any other idea on how to improve the performance?

Comment: If the CPU usage is 100% then I don't think the issue are the images, the problem could lie elsewhere in your code, that would be really weird. Also, are you on simulator or real device?

Comment: I tried it on an iPad Air M1 as well as simulator and had the same experience. The 100% CPU usage is (in my real app) only when swiping trough the the scrollview and the images change constantly. You can also try it in the demo code. Open the simulator and click a few times moderately fast on the switch button.

Comment: I will check the CPU usage tomorrow then. If you can, may you provide a minimal example of the paginated scrollView too? Maybe there's something going on there too, I don't know.

Comment: I can share the code but it has a lot of dependent variables and the problem is exactly the same as in the demo code when the switch button is clicked fast. You can easily see the lag and extremely high CPU usage. This logically destroyes the fluidity of all animation on screen and thats why it is especially noticed in my app. But the cpu usage and lag on image transition is the same in the demo code.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out tomorrow then.

Comment: I just fired it up on the simulator (I don't have a physical Apple device unfortunately) and on average the CPU usage was 50% when tapping the switch button repeatadly. There were spikes of 100%, but that was not the norm. Memory usage is about 90 MB. If you are using a paginated scrollView would you consider using a LazyHStack to avoid render other not visible elements maybe?

Comment: Yeah, that was it man! I think I've found the source of your error. It is beacause you are not using a Lazy kind of stack, you are using a simple VStack or HStack and the memory and CPU usage are going crazy. I've build a simple paginated horizintal scrollView myself and tried both LazyHStack and vanilla HStack and with the latter the app freezes, literally. I'm going to update the code here too with this example.

Comment: I updated the code in the main post to show the problem like it is in my real app. Below there is a link to a video with the problem and CPU usage. It is a LazyVstack but the performance is very bad. It has the be a problem with the image resizing animation while rendering the new images. Maybe there is a way to "preload" the images into memory but that sounds very overengineered.
https://youtu.be/ADhHab87rbs

Comment: @MatteoTripolt I've updated the code. Take a look. I have no more 100% CPU usage like that.

Comment: This fixed the cpu utilization but let an old bug I had before return. It is now possible to get text and pictureset out of sync which is much worse than any lag. To see the problem you have to create another set and swipe a bit faster on the scrollview. I put the demo code above and there is a link the sync problem below. What I think could improve the situation is to store the instance of an image so it doesn't have to create the instance when shown on screen. Maybe this could reduce lag and make it not necessary to implement the out of sync solution.
https://youtu.be/85gC8PHnak8

Comment: I just discovered that without any animation there is NO Lag and you can swipe as fast as you want with CPU utilization of 20%. So the animation is using 80% CPU, thats insane. I am currently trying other animations than linear and easeIn. Maybe there is a more efficient one.